# callback with button feature on dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash app for which the layout is fairly simple. This is my first time using dash, so hopefully someone can help me out here.

What I'm trying to do is get an app user to input 5 features, and then click a submit button that will call a function to return a graph based on those 5 features.

The code I have so far is:

```
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Regression Analyzer for Individual Market Securities', style={'textAlign': 'center'
        }),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id = 'my-date',
        min_date_allowed=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=datetime(2020, 11, 11),
        initial_visible_month=datetime(2017, 8, 5),
        start_date=str(datetime(2015, 11, 1)),
        end_date=str(datetime(2020, 11, 1)))
    ]),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.Dropdown(id = 'MA',
    options=[
        {'label': 'Day Average', 'value': 'Day Average'},
        {'label': '7 Day Avg', 'value': '7 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '50 Day Avg', 'value': '50 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '200 Day Avg', 'value': '200 Day Avg'}
    ])]),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.Input(id = 'Name',
    placeholder='Enter stock ticker ...',
    type='text',
    value='AAPL') 
    ]),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.Slider(id = 'err',
    min=0,
    max=100,
    step=0.5,
    value=10)   
    ])
])

@app.callback()
def compare_to_market1():
    return compare_to_market()
```

The features the function 'compare_to_market1' should call are: start_date, end_date, Name, MA, and err.

As you can see, compare_to_market1 calls the function compare_to_market, and I would prefer to leave it this way as the latter function is quite long, but I can obviously put it in there if need be.

The main thing is I obviously don't know how to set up the app.callback feature to source the proper inputs and pass them to the compare_to_market1 function I want to run.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when your callback must be called ? there is no dependency

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean

Comment: a callback is called when something happends, for example when you changed the selected choice in a drowdown,  but you did not indicate that. AT that level the best is to look at dash plotly documentation / examples

Comment: Yea as I said I don't know how to set up callback, but I've explained what I'd like to do in the post.

Comment: in your question you do not say when you want the callback called nor the input(s) it receives nor the output(s) it produces, it is impossible to help you

Comment: OK, the inputs should come from what's above the app.callback line. Those inputs should be: start_date, end_date, Name, MA, and err. I want whatever the user selects from those to go into the function after the app.callback line. I don't know what output would be here, but the function would be like compare_to_market1(start_date, end_date, Name, MA, and err)

Comment: I put a proposal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to call the callback when anything change.

Very probably you do not want to use *datetime* but *date*.

Replacing your call of *compare_to_market* by a call to *print* to be able to execute the following code and see calls of callback:

```
from datetime import date
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Regression Analyzer for Individual Market Securities', style={'textAlign': 'center'
        }),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id = 'my-date',
        min_date_allowed=date(2015, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=date(2020, 11, 11),
        initial_visible_month=date(2017, 8, 5),
        start_date=str(date(2015, 11, 1)),
        end_date=str(date(2020, 11, 1)))
    ]),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.Dropdown(id = 'MA',
    options=[
        {'label': 'Day Average', 'value': 'Day Average'},
        {'label': '7 Day Avg', 'value': '7 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '50 Day Avg', 'value': '50 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '200 Day Avg', 'value': '200 Day Avg'}
    ])]),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.Input(id = 'Name',
    placeholder='Enter stock ticker ...',
    type='text',
    value='AAPL') 
    ]),
    
    html.Div([     
    dcc.Slider(id = 'err',
    min=0,
    max=100,
    step=0.5,
    value=10)
    ]),
    
    html.Div(id='my-output')
])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("my-date", "start_date"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("my-date", "end_date"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("Name", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("MA", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("err", "value")])
def compare_to_market1(startDate, endDate, name, ma, err):
    print(startDate, endDate, name, ma, err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: This seems right. I have to fix something with the datetime formatting on my end but this helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: @mark21 perhaps you see the first version of my answer, I edited it to use *date* rather than *datetime*, and to add *MA* I missed in the input dependencies of teh callback

Comment: Yea I tried switching out datetime for date, but the problem is a bit different than that. I'm going to post another question that I'll link to you if you want to give it a shot. Just have to convert the datetime regex somehow.

Comment: Actually looks like I can't post it since I got negged for this question. Maybe if you upvote this one they'll let me ask the other one?

Comment: @mark21 your question has vote 0, you cannot post a new one ? The DV was from me because your question unclear, I cannot cancel the DV until you edit your question. If you want edit your question for instance to make it clear saying you want the callback must be called on any change in start_date, end_date, Name, MA, and err.